# Centering double accents in math with bold symbols

Tags: formatting, accents, bm

I'm having some trouble getting double accents to centralise over a letter in a math environment, in combination with bold math. For example,

```
\dot{\hat{d}}_{lx}
```

Gives

[image: Correct markup]

which is what how I would like the variable to be formed. The problem comes when I try and use bold math, from the bm package, to denote a vector. For example using

```
\bm{\dot{\hat{d}}}_{lx}
```

Gives

[image]

with the dot no longer properly centralised. I've tried every combination of the ordering that I can think of but I cannot get the dot to remain central. Ideally, I would like the "d" and associated accents to be bold, and the subscript not to be bold. If needs be however, I will take all bold as long as the dot is centralised.

Thanks!